# Unit testing Vue composition functions

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm attempting to write a data-fetching "hook" (not entirely clear what the word for this is in Vue, but a state function that does not render a template). The Hook takes an asynchronous data resolver as a parameter. The hook itself is very simple, it simply adds loading state to a function that returns a promise.

```js
import { ref, watch } from "vue";

export function useDataFetcher<T>(
  resolver: () => Promise<T>,
) {
  const isLoading = ref(false);
  const data = ref<T>();
  watch(resolver, () => {
    isLoading.value = true;
    resolver(...parameters)
      .then((fetchedData) => {
        data.value = fetchedData;
      })
      .finally(() => {
        isLoading.value = false;
      });
  });
  return {
    isLoading: isLoading.value,
    data,
    parameters,
  };
}
```

I am attempting to write a test against this function to ensure that the isLoading method is updating correctly:

```js
import { useDataFetcher } from "./useDataFetcher";
test("While the fetcher is loading data, isLoading should be true", async () => {
  const promise = new Promise<void>((resolver) =>
    setTimeout(() => resolver(), 2000)
  );
  const { isLoading } = useDataFetcher(() => promise);
  expect(isLoading).toBeTruthy();
  await promise;

  expect(isLoading).toBeFalsy();
});
```

As written, this test is not working. I have not seen a lot of information in the interwebs about testing these state functions in Vue.
There are two stack overflow questions that seem related:
[Is it possible to test a Vue 3 Composition library which uses inject without a wrapping component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68697265/is-it-possible-to-test-a-vue-3-composition-library-which-uses-inject-without-a-w)

and
[How to unit test standalone Vue composition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59957561/how-to-unit-test-standalone-vue-composition)

But neither of these seem to quite scratch the itch I'm having here.

In React, you have the @testing-library/react-hooks library to manage these tests, and it makes it very simple. It seems to me that I'm missing something to the effect of `await Vue.nextTick()`.

So, finally, the question: What exactly is the best way to test these Vue hooks that don't render templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I ended up putting together a solution for my problem and publishing an npm module for it: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-composable-function-tester. I would love feedback on the solution.

Here's an example of what it looks like:

### Test:

```js
it("Reacts to a resolving promise", async () => {
  const resolvedData = {
    hello: "world",
  };
  const promise = Promise.resolve(resolvedData);
  const composable = mountComposableFunction(() =>
    useAsynchronousLoader(() => promise)
  );
  await composable.nextTick();
  expect(composable.data.isLoading.value).toBe(true);
  await promise;
  await composable.nextTick();
  expect(composable.data.data.value).toStrictEqual(resolvedData);
  await composable.nextTick();
  expect(composable.data.isLoading.value).toBe(false);
});
```

### Implementation:

```js
export function useAsynchronousLoader<T>(promiseCreator: () => Promise<T>) {
  const isLoading = ref(false);
  const data = ref<T>();
  const error = ref<object>();
  isLoading.value = true;
  promiseCreator()
    .then((newData) => {
      data.value = newData;
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      error.value = e;
    })
    .finally(() => {
      isLoading.value = false;
    });
  return {
    isLoading,
    data,
    error,
  };
}
```

EDIT: Improved code samples.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the loading ref to keep the reactivity.

```js
  return {
    isLoading,
    data,
    parameters,
  };
```

By passing `isLoading.value` you only pass the value at that time and loose the reactivity